# What do we call an internship of which acceptance of the applicants is based on an interview?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, formality, phrase-requests

I am writing a cover letter in which I want to mention that I was chosen among *2000* students due to my success in an interview. Is there a general adjective that can be used to describe such an internship?

Comment: Would screened work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I was accepted as an intern after a rigorous interview process" or "I was accepted into a very competitive internship program".

Or, more directly, you can say, "I was selected for an internship program that only accepted one student out of two thousand applicants".